# Xcode stuck on start loading project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

My xcode stopped working properlly and I don't know why.

By launching my flutter project in Xcode today da loading runner is infinity and app does not respond anymore.

This happens with any project even if i start a new project the problem is the same.

Can you help please ?

(I reinstalled Xcode 14.2 the problem is the same)

Issue image

[image: 1]

I already tried to delete cache files, reboot the mac, reinstall xcode.
Nothing worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, only opened the project after disabling iCloud

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I figured that if I disable the internet connection there is no problem anymore with the launch. And once the xcode properly launched, I enable the internet connection again, and it seems to work